# how do I differentiate this function implicitly

Tags: implicit-differentiation

How do I differentiate $$\frac{(x^2 - 4y^2)} {(x^2 + xy^2)} = 2$$ implicitly? I did it by bringing the denominator over to the other side, and I got $$\frac{-(2x + 2y^2)}{(4xy + 8y)}$$

---

Here are the images of the question and the suggested answer.
[image: Question]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how you'd do it:
We have $$\frac{x^2-4y^2}{x^2+xy^2}=2$$
So$$x^2-4y^2=2x^2+2xy^2$$
Differentiating implicitly:
$$2x-8y\frac{dy}{dx}=4x+(2y^2+4xy\frac{dy}{dx})$$(using product rule as well) so
$$4xy\frac{dy}{dx}+8y\frac{dy}{dx}=-2x-2y^2$$
so$$\frac{dy}{dx}(4xy+8y)=-2x-2y^2$$
and finally $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2x-2y^2}{4xy+8y}$$
I hope that helped!

Comment: yup that's how I did it as well, but the answer key seem to suggest that it is dy/dx = (2x - y^2) / (2xy + 16y)

Comment: I'm not sure why it'd say that, I can't spot any mistake in my working. Can you?

Comment: neither can I which is why I'm really confused

Comment: Probably just a mistake in the textbook/website. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I've just added the relevant images

Comment: Is it a textbook? I'd say it's simply an error.